# Spring-test's @Rollback doesn't rollback anything

Tags: java, transactions, spring-test

Working code below:

```
//import everything

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Test2.TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
public class Test2 {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @BeforeTransaction
    public void createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        DataSourceUtils .getConnection(datasource)
                        .createStatement()
                        .execute("CREATE TABLE USERS (id bigint, size bigint, primary key (id))");
    }

    @Rollback
    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {
        DataSourceUtils .getConnection(datasource)
                        .createStatement()
                        .execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (5, 5)");
    }

    @AfterTransaction
    public void dropTable() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = DataSourceUtils  .getConnection(datasource)
                                        .createStatement()
                                        .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS");
        boolean isEmpty = !rs.next();
        if (isEmpty) {
            System.out.println("Rollback succeeded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Rollback failed");
        }
        rs.close();

        datasource  .getConnection()
                    .createStatement()
                    .execute("DROP TABLE USERS");
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataSource driverManagerDataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            String dbURI = "database/tests/DerbyDB/db";
            String connectionString = "jdbc:derby:" + dbURI;
            if (!new File(dbURI).exists()) connectionString += ";create=true";
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(connectionString);
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            return driverManagerDataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
            PlatformTransactionManager ptm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(driverManagerDataSource());
            return ptm;
        }
    }
}
```

Solved question:
I want to rollback database state after each test using @Rollback annotation. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

Here is my test class:

```
//import everything

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Test2.TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
public class Test2 {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @BeforeTransaction
    public void createTable() throws SQLException {
        datasource  .getConnection()
                    .createStatement()
                    .execute("CREATE TABLE USERS (id bigint, size bigint, primary key (id))");
    }

    @Rollback
    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {
        datasource  .getConnection()
                    .createStatement()
                    .execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (5, 5)");
    }

    @AfterTransaction
    public void dropTable() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = datasource   .getConnection()
                                    .createStatement()
                                    .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS");
        boolean isEmpty = !rs.next();
        if (isEmpty) {
            System.out.println("Rollback succeeded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Rollback failed");
        }
        rs.close();

        datasource  .getConnection()
                    .createStatement()
                    .execute("DROP TABLE USERS");
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataSource driverManagerDataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            String dbURI = "database/tests/DerbyDB/db";
            String connectionString = "jdbc:derby:" + dbURI;
            if (!new File(dbURI).exists()) connectionString += ";create=true";
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(connectionString);
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            return driverManagerDataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
            PlatformTransactionManager ptm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(driverManagerDataSource());
            return ptm;
        }
    }
}
```

Spring claims it rolled back database, which is not true, because record remains.
How do I make it work?

```
gru 01, 2016 12:26:14 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext startTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@457c9034 testClass = Test2, testInstance = tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2@345f69f3, testMethod = test@Test2, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@e15b7e8 testClass = Test2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2$TestConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@3bf9ce3e]; rollback [true]
gru 01, 2016 12:26:14 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@457c9034 testClass = Test2, testInstance = tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2@345f69f3, testMethod = test@Test2, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@e15b7e8 testClass = Test2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2$TestConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
Rollback failed
gru 01, 2016 12:26:14 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@ae45eb6: startup date [Thu Dec 01 12:26:12 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

The full log is presented below:

```
gru 01, 2016 12:26:12 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
gru 01, 2016 12:26:12 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@69d9c55, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@13a57a3b, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7ca48474, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@337d0578, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@59e84876, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@61a485d2]
gru 01, 2016 12:26:12 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@ae45eb6: startup date [Thu Dec 01 12:26:12 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
gru 01, 2016 12:26:13 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
gru 01, 2016 12:26:13 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
gru 01, 2016 12:26:14 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext startTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@457c9034 testClass = Test2, testInstance = tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2@345f69f3, testMethod = test@Test2, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@e15b7e8 testClass = Test2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2$TestConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@3bf9ce3e]; rollback [true]
gru 01, 2016 12:26:14 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@457c9034 testClass = Test2, testInstance = tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2@345f69f3, testMethod = test@Test2, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@e15b7e8 testClass = Test2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class tyvrel.tastas.persistence.Test2$TestConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
Rollback failed
gru 01, 2016 12:26:14 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@ae45eb6: startup date [Thu Dec 01 12:26:12 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're creating a new, independent Spring context manually in your test method, which during its initialization creates the table.

Since that context uses its own transaction manager and data source, it won't be affected by the `@Rollback` annotation - that one is processed in context of the (implicit) spring context defined for the whole test class.

---

Also note that in some DBs, you cannot rollback `CREATE` commands (not sure about Derby though).

---

**Update**

Another issue is that you're not actually using the transaction manager when you get the connection through `datasource.getConnection()`.

From [`DataSourceTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) documentation:

> Application code is required to retrieve the JDBC Connection via `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource)` instead of a standard Java EE-style `DataSource.getConnection()` call. Spring classes such as `JdbcTemplate` use this strategy implicitly.

Comment: Do you you mean, that annotating test class with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDerbyDatabaseInitializer.TestConfiguration.class)` and deleting implict context will make `@Rollback` annotation work?

Comment: 1) You need to use the Spring context created by the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation (i.e. do what you wrote); don't create any other contexts to avoid confusion, 2) don't create any other connections to database programmatically (`DriverManager.getConnection()`) to avoid using a non-managed connection accidentally, 3) test it on something you know can be rolled back (i.e. `INSERT`, not `CREATE TABLE`) - create the database in `@BeforeTransaction` method.

Comment: Thank you, that answer made me understand more about testing Spring. Also I have updated code according to your comment, but I still can't get it working.

Comment: Just to make it clear: the solution is to use `JdbcTemplate` (or `DataSourceUtils`) instead of working directly with the `DataSource`. - Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line `con.close();` in `printTableName()` method caused the issuse.

The transaction is committed when closing the connection.

It is better use **entitymanager** or [**spring data jpa repository**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) to handle the transaction.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, deleting `con.close();` doesn't solve a problem.

Comment: @Tyvrel  Did you try explicitly rollback? `con.rollback();`

Comment: Of course. It doesn't work either. And misses the point - I need to learn how `@Rollback` works and I couldn't figure out easier exercise than executing simple sql script.

Comment: `con.close()` closes a programmatically created connection that is not managed by Spring's transaction manager at any time.